# Date conversion YYYY-MM-DD to YYYY-DD-MM in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a hive table having data in string format as 2015-03-09 10:00:00.

I want to view it with my Select statement as 2015-09-03 10:00:00
can i know how do i do that?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the date in built udfs for this like :

```
select FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp('2016-03-28 00:00:00','yyyy-MM-dd'),'yyyy-dd-MM');
```

The output for this query would be :
        2016-28-03